# AngularJS: tabs and controller passing data through

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, controller, data-sharing

I would like to create an AngularJS app in which I woud have a page containing multiple tabs. Since each tab would have a very specific business logic, I am wondering what would be the best way to achieve such a thing, knowing that I want to be able to pass through data from tab to tab. The user would have to follow a specific workflow, starting on the first tab, clicking on a button and landing on the second tab, able to see and use data he generated from the first tab, and so on.

I have come across this articles : [Top 18 Most Common AngularJS Developer Mistakes](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes) which talks about `controllerAs` attribute. Would it be something I could use to have let's say:

- a route provider with a main controller
- a main view including each of my tabs' view
- a view per tab with an associated controller
- use `controllerAs` to be able to pass given shared data from a controller to another

**UPDATE**

Apparently it is clear that it cannot work if I do something like that:

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstController', function(){
    this.myVar = "I am from FirstController";
});
angular.module('myApp').controller('SecondController', function(){
    this.myVar = "I am from SecondController";
});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController as FC">
    {{FC.myVar}}
    {{SC.myVar}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondController as SC">
    {{FC.myVar}}
    {{SC.myVar}}
</div>
```

How could I make something like this nice and working? Or should I really have shared variables amongst the controllers provided from a MainController, wrapping these two?

Thank you for your helps.

Kind regards,

Comment: try and give a look at [this link](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/), could be helpful

Comment: Hehe I was just reading it thank you. Seems like that `controllerAs` attribute helps for nested scopes, but not really in my case, does it? I must start set up a project and see by myself the issues I am encountering..

Comment: I think you can try an have a main controller for the tabs page, and then have a nested scope for each tab, but yes,  I guess you have to try it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I cna't see how that should work, you have to share variable provided from a Main Controller, that's what I ment in my last comment....